# Retrieve data from a Json file to fulfill a select box in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ckeditor

I created a new plugin under ckeditor that contains a select box and I want to fulfill its options with data from a json file.
This is what my Json contains:

```
{"services":[
{"linkUrl":"localhost:8080/mySite/contents/service1"},{"linkUrl":"localhost:8080/mySite/contents/service2"},{"linkUrl":"localhost:8080/mySite/contents/service3"},{"linkUrl":"localhost:8080/mySite/contents/service4"}
]}
```

And this is the code that I developed :

```
{
    type: 'select',
    id: 'services',
    label: 'Services',
    items: [''],
    onLoad: function() {
        (function($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/modules/design/files/services.json",
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#services').each(function(key,val) {
                        if (key == "linkUrl") {
                            $('#services').append('<option value="'+ key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                        }
                    });
                }  
            });
        })(jQuery);
    },                                

    commit : function( data )
    {
        data.services = this.getValue();
    }
},
```

After executing my code the select box is still empty.

Comment: are you sure that the data is coming in success function

Comment: Hello Shubhranshu, excuse me I am not familiar with this syntax but that is what I found in Internet. there is a few examples like this one : http://s1.ckeditor.com/sites/default/files/uploads/plugin_5.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just some syntax issues but the idea is correct, this code works fine.

```
{   
    type: 'select',
    id: 'services',
    label: 'services',
    items: [''],
    onLoad: function() {
        (function($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/modules/design/files/services.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) { console.log("data.services.length " + data.services.length);
                    for( i = 0 ; i < data.services.length ; i++ ){
                        curservice = data.services[i];
                        $('.cke_dialog_ui_input_select').append($('<option>').text(curservice.name).attr('value', curservice.key));
                    }
                }  
            });
    })(jQuery);
},
```